# How can I add soft constraints in Z3 ml api?

Tags: z3, solver, smt

I'm trying to solve some smt equations with Z3 OCaml api.
I need to add some soft constraint using `Z3.Optimize.add_soft` function, but I don't know what the parameters of the function mean and cannot find any description or example for that.
Merlin just type that `Z3.Optimize.add_soft : Z3.Optimize.optimize -> Z3.Expr.expr -> string -> Z3.Symbol.symbol -> Z3.Optimize.handle`, and I found some descriptions in [this page](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/ml/z3.mli), but I don't know how to add option that means `:weight 10`, for example.

In other words, I want to call `Z3.Optimize.add_soft` function as following smt2 format

`(assert-soft e :weight 10)`

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, never mind. I find it myself by using `Z3.Goal.to_string` function. It turns out that in `Z3.optimize.add_soft` function, the parameter of type `string` is weight value as string, and `Z3.Symbol.symbol` is `:id` as smt2 format.

Comment: So, I just call `Z3.optimize.add_soft e "10" [some id symbol]` and is ok.

Comment: you should make your comments a proper answer and the accept it, comments and unanswered questions may be deleted by the system eventually.